# Toggle a part of description as internal in swagger API doc

Tags: yaml, swagger, documentation, openapi

I have an API documented in swagger and i want to have some kind of toggle to make a certain part of the description internal.

```
parameter:
  - name: abc
    description: |
      line1
      line2
      line3
```

in the above example, is it possible to introduce some kind of togggle so that the line3 does not get shown in the final document. I am using openapi-filter.js to mark the objects and attributes as x-internal but i have no idea how to do it to toggle a part of description.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a feature in OpenAPI (and wasn't in Swagger as far as I know) to hide part of a description as you describe. I recommend using your own `x-internal-info` field or something that you can parse for the appropriate audience. Sorry this isn't the answer you were hoping for!